# SiteLock Implementing IObjectSafety BUT Not Working in IE

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, internet-explorer, activex

I have used the SiteLock 1.15 template to restrict domain access to my ActiveX control so that only a list of pre-approved domain can use it.

Everything compiles ok, and even the SiteList.exe application that is supplied with the SiteLock template correctly shows the list of domains that I defined inside the ActiveX Control.

Also, The OLE Object Viewer correctly shows my ActiveX component exposing the IObjectSafety and IObjectWithSite interfaces.

It's only IE8 that is acting up and not honoring the IObjectSafety interface, so what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the test website in Exploder's trusted zone, with all security options turned off; so Exploder didn't even negotiate with the IObjectSafety interface.

When I modified the security option, Exploder started communicating with the interface so all is rainbows and bubbles.